# Re-enter the age if the user put a letter as an input

Tags: c++

Our professor told us to create a function that if the user enters a letter on age it will let the user to re-enter the age again. But, only the age will update without inputting name again,
I tried, but here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
string inputName, inputGender, inputBirthday;
int inputAge, inputChoice;
ofstream fileOutput("Example.txt");
int getAge() {
    cin>>inputAge;
    if (inputAge <= 50) {
        fileOutput<<inputAge<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"Error: Re-enter your age: ";
        cin>>inputChoice;
        getAge();
    }
}

int main() {
    cout<<"Enter your Name:     ";
    getline(cin, inputName);
    fileOutput<<inputName<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your Age:      ";
    getAge();
    cout<<"Enter your Gender:   ";
    getline(cin, inputGender);
    fileOutput<<inputGender<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your Birthday: ";
    getline(cin, inputBirthday);
    fileOutput<<inputBirthday<<endl;
    fileOutput.close();
    cout<<"Done!\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how will i do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to return an int, there is no point in declaring getAge with an `int` return

```
void getAge()
{
    std::string line;
    int i;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> i)
        {
           if (ss.eof())
           {
              break;
           }
        }
        std::cout << "Please re-enter the age as an integer" << std::endl;
    }
    if (i <= 50)
    {
       fileOutput << i <<endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: it says "variable std::stringstream ss' has initializer but incomplete type "

Comment: @user3288922: Do you have an include for string? e.g. `#include <string>`?

Comment: @user3288922: include sstream

Comment: Wait, what is the use of                                               "while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> i)
        {
           if (ss.eof())
           {
              break;
           }
        }
        std::cout << "Please re-enter the age as an integer" << std::endl;
    }"?

Comment: @user3288922: It keeps reading input until the `stringstream` can take the input and make it an integer. If it matches, then it breaks out of the loop. So if it matches on the first try, then it only runs once. Otherwise, it tells the user to enter in the age again. That's the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting a number while throwing away bad input is more of a hassle than I'd like.  Here's a general approach:

```
template <typename T>
T get_on_line(std::istream& is, const std::string& retry_msg)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        T x;
        char c;
        if (iss >> x)
            if (iss >> c)
                throw std::runtime_error("unexpected trailing garbage on line");
            else
                return x;
        else
            std::cerr << retry_msg << '\n';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int num = get_on_line<int>(std::cin, "unable to parse age from line, please type it again");
```